# How do you remove this Schlage double cylinder deadbolt? (M8209)

Tags: deadbolt

I've dealt with a lot of deadbolts, but unsure about this one. I don't want to damage it either. It's an old Schlage that I am trying to replace. After removing the cover on the inner side of the deadbolt, I was stumped. On the inside of the cover, it reads M8209 which is the only clue I have about it, but Google and YouTube weren't too helpful.

I'm thinking there are screws under the two metal circles, or "caps", but they don't budge at all. It looks like someone has previously tried to removed the two "caps" from the deep gouges.

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

[image: Back no cover]